# Global access password for ipython notebook

Tags: .htaccess, security, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In `ipython notebook` I found two (more or less) ways to secure my **remote server** which is running as my **notebook host**.

1. The `c.NotebookApp.password` option in the config secures the notebook from write access.
2. The `--read-only` flag allows not authenticated useres only to view my notebook.

But with point `2.` I am not getting warm.
The problem is that it allows **anybody** to view my notebook. Actually I only want some privileged users to view my notebook. Until now I havn't found any way to do so.

Is there the possibility to secure my notebook globaly with, e.g. a `.htaccess` file or anything else?
In that case I can give all users the website password and I can change the notebook with my `1.`option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanisme for auth and read-only notebook in IPython. And security is complex enough to start adding option for Auth+Read-only at the moment.

You can also install a local copy of nbviewer and/or use nbconvert to export your notebook as static html, and serve using a classical appache/.htaccess scheme.